# Issue creating a text file from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I am attempting to create a text file while with a variable in it's name:

```
mkdir logs
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
set filename=build_%mydate%_%mytime%
gradlew build > I:\TNB_XPort_Redux\logs\%filename%x.txt
```

When I run the batch file I get this as an output:
[image: Issue]

Any ideas how to get the file to be properly created as a text file?

**Edit**: I am expecting the file to be named: build_date_time.*txt* instead of build_date_time

Comment: Echo the filename variable before you run gradlew. You may have some sort of weird break character or something. Otherwise, recheck your code and make sure the output file path actually ends in .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to create a blank text file at your chosen path:

```
mkdir logs
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
break>"I:\TNB_XPort_Redux\logs\build_%mydate%_%mytime%.txt"
```

This snip of code would create a dir "logs", and a blank file "build_%mydate%_%mytime%.txt" in that directory.

Alternatively you could use the longer method of setting a filename variable as you did in your example.

```
mkdir logs
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
set filename=build_%mydate%_%mytime%
break>"I:\TNB_XPort_Redux\logs\%filename%.txt"
```

All in all they both do the same thing

Comment: This worked out perfectly, thank you. I was missing the quotes and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```dos
mkdir logs
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set "mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b")
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/: " %%a in ('time /t') do (set "mytime=%%a%%b")
set "filename=build_%mydate%_%mytime%"
gradlew build > "I:\TNB_XPort_Redux\logs\%filename%.txt"
```

While in my system I can not reproduce the observed behaviour, it can be recreated by inserting a space after the timestamp. The quotes will prevent inclusion of ending spaces at the end of the lines and problems when spaces in file names.